# Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=D_{8}$ and $H=\{e,a^2,b,a^2b\}.$ Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I know that in order to be a subgroup the following three conditions must be satisfied:

- If $x,y \in H$ then $xy \in H$
- $e \in H$
- If $x \in H$ then $x^{-1} \in H$

However, is there a quick way to check that the first condition is satisfied or do I need to check each pair individually?

Comment: I assume $a$ is rotation by $\pi/2$ and $b$ is one of the reflections?

Comment: @Bungo Yes that's right.

Comment: You mostly need to do all pairs...but writing out a multiplication table and filling it in as you go will help that process go pretty fast.

Comment: To check, for example, that the product of $b$ and $a^2 b$ is in $H$, use the facts that $ba = a^{-1}b$ and $a^{-2} = a^2$ and $b^2 = 1$ to simplify $ba^2 b = a^{-2} b^2 = a^2 b^2 = a^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can confirm by brute force calculation that whenever $x,y \in H$ we have $xy \in H$ and $x^{-1} \in H$. It's not too difficult but it's also not very fun or enlightening.

We can work smarter instead of harder (and a bit more "group theoretically") as follows.

Observe that $A = \langle a^2\rangle$ and $B = \langle b \rangle$ both have order $2$. Also, note that $a^2$ commutes with $a$ and $b$, the latter because $a^2 b = ba^{-2} = ba^2$. Since $a$ and $b$ generate $G$, this means that $a^2$ commutes with all elements of $G$, and therefore $A \lhd G$.

Therefore, $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$. Its order is
$$|AB| = \frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap B|} = \frac{2\cdot 2}{1} = 4$$
Since $AB$ contains $e$, $a^2$, $b$, and $a^2 b$, and all of these elements are distinct, we conclude that these are in fact all of the elements of $AB$. Therefore $AB = \{e, a^2, b, a^2 b\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ as claimed.

---

Here is an alternative argument that $A \lhd G$ which allows us to keep our hands cleaner. The subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ has order $4$, hence index $2$ in $G$, and therefore $\langle a \rangle \lhd G$. Then, $A = \langle a^2 \rangle$ is the unique subgroup of $\langle a \rangle$ with order $2$, hence $A$ is characteristic in $\langle a \rangle$. Thus we have $A$ characteristic in $\langle a \rangle$, and $\langle a \rangle$ normal in $G$, so consequently $A \lhd G$.